# Bash script not exiting after completion, why?

Tags: bash, visual-studio-code, automation, scripting, git-bash

install-extensions.sh (installs VSCode extensions)

```sh
code --install-extension adpyke.codesnap --force &
code --install-extension ahmadalli.vscode-nginx-conf --force &
code --install-extension alefragnani.Bookmarks --force &
code --install-extension arturock.gitstash --force &
code --install-extension csholmq.excel-to-markdown-table --force &
code --install-extension dariofuzinato.vue-peek --force &
code --install-extension dbaeumer.vscode-eslint --force &
code --install-extension donjayamanne.githistory --force &
code --install-extension dracula-theme.theme-dracula --force &
code --install-extension ecmel.vscode-html-css --force &
code --install-extension esbenp.prettier-vscode --force &
code --install-extension formulahendry.code-runner --force &
code --install-extension Gruntfuggly.todo-tree --force &
code --install-extension jakob101.RelativePath --force &
code --install-extension jasonnutter.search-node-modules --force &
code --install-extension MariusAlchimavicius.json-to-ts --force &
code --install-extension mark-wiemer.vscode-autohotkey-plus-plus --force &
code --install-extension mikestead.dotenv --force &
code --install-extension mushan.vscode-paste-image --force &
code --install-extension mwpb.java-prettier-formatter --force &
code --install-extension naumovs.color-highlight --force &
code --install-extension nemesv.copy-file-name --force &
code --install-extension netcorext.uuid-generator --force &
code --install-extension octref.vetur --force &
code --install-extension pustelto.bracketeer --force &
code --install-extension raynigon.nginx-formatter --force &
code --install-extension ritwickdey.LiveServer --force &
code --install-extension svelte.svelte-vscode --force &
code --install-extension tlent.jest-snapshot-language-support --force &
code --install-extension tomoki1207.selectline-statusbar --force &
code --install-extension Tyriar.sort-lines --force &
code --install-extension vscode-icons-team.vscode-icons --force &
code --install-extension waderyan.gitblame --force &
code --install-extension WallabyJs.quokka-vscode --force &
code --install-extension wenfangdu.faster-new --force &
code --install-extension wenfangdu.jump --force &
code --install-extension wenfangdu.snippet-generator --force &
code --install-extension wmaurer.change-case --force &
code --install-extension yzane.markdown-pdf --force &
code --install-extension zengxingxin.sort-js-object-keys --force
```

Run `sh install-extensions.sh`, the script doesn't exit after completion, why is that?

P.S. I'm using Git Bash on Windows.

Comment: Why are you running all of those installs (except the last one) in the background?

Comment: @lurker Are there better options? I tried using `&&`, but the installation speed is way too slow compared to using `&`.

Comment: I just wasn't sure if vscode was happy with them all running in parallel.